# How to wait for the completion of the function to start the next one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

How to wait for the completion of the `fetchData()` function to start the next `fetchForecastData()`? we need lon and lat data from `fetchData` to use them in `fetchForecastData()`. If you add the `fetchForecastData()` function to the code when `fetchData()` has already been loaded, everything works, but after a reboot, everything flies away

```
function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
  const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState([]);
  const [weatherForecast, setWeatherForecast] = useState([]);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState('');
  const [lon, setLon] = useState('');

  const addSearchCity = (search) => {
    setLocation(search);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid={API}&units=metric`,
    );
    setCurrentWeather(res.data);
    setLat(res.data.coord.lat);
    setLon(res.data.coord.lon);
  };
  const fetchForecastData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid={API}&units=metric`,
    );
    setWeatherForecast(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchForecastData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I don't think it is clear what your issue is. I wonder, could you repair the title by removing "help me please" and perhaps rewriting it to something meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
    await fetchData();
    await fetchForecastData();
  }
  getData()
}, []);
```

Judging by the code you posted, I'm pretty sure you know that using `await` is the way to make one async function run after another. I think the piece you were missing was how to use async / await inside of a `useEffect()` hook. And the answer to that is to declare an async function inside of the `useEffect` function and then call it right away. I hope that helps.